# Python - How to  build and access a large collection of data without maxing out memory or slowing processing to a halt

Tags: python, memory, collections, persistence, containers

I am writing a script in Python to QC data in a proprietary ESRI database table.  The purpose of the script is not to modify invalid data, but simply to report invalid data to the user via a csv file.  I am using ESRI's ArcPy package to access each individual record with arcpy.SearchCursor.  The SearchCursor is the only way to access each individual record in the ESRI formats.

As I scroll through each record of the tables, I do multiple QC checks to validate specific business logic.  One of those checks is looking for duplicate data in particular fields.  One of those fields may be geometry.  I have done this by creating an empty container object for each of those fields and as I check each record I use the following logic.

```
for field in dupCheckFields:
    if row.getValue(field) in fieldValues[field]: dupValues.add(row.getValue(idField))
    else: fieldValues[field].append(row.getValue(field))
```

The above code is an example of the basic logic I use.  Where I am running into trouble is the fact that each of these tables may contain anywhere from 5000 records to 10 million records.  I either run out of memory or the performance grinds to a halt.

I have tried the following container types: sets, lists, dictionaries, ZODB + BList, and Shelve.

With the in-memory types (sets, lists, dictionaries) the process is very fast at the start, but as it progresses it gets much slower.  We these types, if I have many records in the table I will run out of memory.  With the persistent data types, I don't run out of memory, but it takes a very long time to process.

I only need the data while the script is running and any persistent data files will be deleted upon completion.

Question: Is there a better container type out there to provide low-memory storage of lots of data without a large cost in performance when accessing the data?

System: Win7 64-bit, Python 2.6.5 32-bit, 4gb RAM

Thanks in advance for your help.

EDIT:

Sample SQLite code:

```
import sqlite3, os, arcpy, timeit

fc = r"path\to\feature\class"

# test feature class was in ESRI ArcSDE format and contained "." characters separating database name, owner, and feature class name
fcName = fc.split(".")[-1]

# convert ESRI data types to SQLite data types
dataTypes = {"String":"text","Guid":"text","Double":"real","SmallInteger":"integer"}

fields = [(field.name,dataTypes[field.type]) for field in arcpy.ListFields(fc) if field.name != arcpy.Describe(fc).OIDFieldName]

# SQL string to create table in SQLite with same schema as feature class
createTableString = """create table %s(%s,primary key(%s))""" % (fcName,",\n".join('%s %s' % field for field in fields),fields[0][0])

# SQL string to insert data into SQLite table
insertString = """insert into %s values(%s)""" % (fcName, ",".join(["?" for i in xrange(len(fields))]))

# location to save SQLite database
loc = r'C:\TEMPORARY_QC_DATA'

def createDB():
    conn = sqlite3.connect(os.path.join(loc,'database.db'))
    cur = conn.cursor()

    cur.execute(createTableString)

    conn.commit()

    rows = arcpy.SearchCursor(fc)

    i = 0
    for row in rows:
        try:
            cur.execute(insertString, [row.getValue(field[0]) for field in fields])
            if i % 10000 == 0:
                print i, "records"
                conn.commit()
            i += 1
        except sqlite3.IntegrityError: pass
    print i, "records"

t1 = timeit.Timer("createDB()","from __main__ import createDB")

print t1.timeit(1)
```

Unfortunately I cannot share the test data I used with this code, however it was an ESRI ArcSDE geodatabase table containing approx. 10 fields and approx. 7 mil records.

I tried to use `timeit` to determine how long this process took, however after 2 hours of processing, only 120,000 records were complete.

Answer (score 0):

If you store hashes in (compressed) files, you could stream through them to compare hashes to look for duplicates. Streaming usually has very low memory requirements — you can set the buffer you want, say, one line per hashed record. The tradeoff is generally time, particularly if you add compression, but if you order the files by some criteria, then you may be able to walk through the uncompressed streams to more quickly compare records.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean by hashes in files and streaming through them.  Would this just mean saving data in a txt file in a predefined organization and simply reading through the txt to find particular entries?

Comment: I've investigated hashes, and this does seem like it might be a possible solution.  However, once I have identified duplicate hashes, how can I find the original data to report this to the user?

Comment: Keep a sorted array of associations between hashes and identification keys (e.g., row numbers or IDs). When you find a match of hashes between two tables, you'll have record keys to do the lookups you'll need. You could use JSON or some other serialization format. If you use JSON, it's a text file that you can compress (if disk space is at a premium) and decompress to a stream that you can walk through, hash by hash.

Answer (score 0):

I think I'd evaluate storing persistent data (such as the known field vals and counts) in a SQLite database. It is of course a trade off between memory usage and performance.

If you use a persistence mechanism that supports concurrent access, you can probably parallelise the processing of your data, using [multiprocessing](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html). Once complete, a summary of errors can be generated from the database.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I tried SQLite and it was the slowest performance of everything I have tried.  I tried a dataset with 30,000 records and it took over 2 hours to get to 14,000 records before I had to stop it.  I realize the ESRI SearchCursor is a fairly slow way to iterate through records in a table, but just iterating through the table without loading it into memory or a persistent data type took a couple minutes.

Comment: Are you able to make your code available? What about the data file?

Comment: I have added the SQLite sample code to the original post.  Unfortunately, I am unable to share the data file.  Thanks again.